# Setting up MX records for different mail providers

Tags: email, web, dns, mx-record

Is it possible to have certain email addresses served by one provider and another by another with MX records and priority setting?

E.g.:

person2@domainname.com from mail provider 1
person1@domainname.com from mail provider 2

Is this achievable with MX records for both?  Or would the availability of both servers cause a mailbox not found error for the address at the provider with the lower priority MX record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MX-records target the whole domain and assume that the indicated server is authoritative for all mailboxes in that domain. So no, you cannot do that level of distinction with DNS records.